# Javascript TypeError: can't convert undefined to object

Tags: javascript, object, undefined, typeerror

```
var horizont, vertikal = new Array ()

for (var i=0; i < 9; i++) 
{
horizont[i] = new Array ();
vertikal[i] = new Array ()
}
```

That's what the console told me:

> TypeError: can't convert undefined to object

```
horizont[i] = new Array ();
```

(if I would erase it from the code he says the same with vertikal )

except from some other empty strings getiing born it's the beginning of my code...
where is the mistake?
Is it so ovious that I don't see it?

Comment: You declare `horizont` as `undefined`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is because you did not define `horizont` as an Array. You are using a comma to separate your variable so it is undefined. It does not use the `new Array()` from vertikal.

If you take your code

```
var horizont, vertikal = new Array ()
```

And write it out to use multiple variable, the error would pop out.

```
var horizont;
var vertikal = new Array();
```

You need to specify both as Arrays.

```
var horizont = [], 
    vertikal = [];
```

Comment: That's not the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)